# why use static keyword in method

Tags: static-methods

When I think of something that's "static". I think of something that doesn't change. Does that mean non-static methods can change, but static methods don't? Do they behave differently?

Comment: Most of the answers are not in the spirit of the question IMHO. The asker is trying to point out that the keyword name "static" is not very appropriate. Isn't it?

Comment: So are you trying to imply, that "static variables" are entities which are static but variable? :-)

Comment: @MahendraSK: do you *know* what "static" means? Have you tried to *find out*? -1, no research effort shown.

Answer (score 4):

(Assuming you're talking about C# here - it means slightly different things in different languages, so you'd be wise to tag your question with exactly what you're asking about.)

The word "static" here is used to mean "related to a type rather than to a particular instance of a type". I believe it was originally used because the compiler could determine *statically*  what a member meant, as opposed to the member in use being determined *dynamically* at execution time (e.g. invoking a virtual method) but it's lost a lot of that meaning now :(

The "static = related to the type itself, not an instance" meaning is consistent throughout C#, including:

- Static variables / methods / events / properties
- Static classes (no instances are ever created)
- Static constructor (used to initialize the type itself)
- Operators (not called *on* an instance - values are provided as parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Static methods don't require a class instance. That is the main difference.

- Static

  ClassName.MethodName();
- Not static

  var obj = new ClassName();
   obj.MethodName();

Answer (score 0):

Static methods neither require an instance of the class nor can they implicitly access the data (or this, self, Me, etc.) of such an instance.

Answer (score 0):

They do not behave different. Like said before, the main difference is that you don't need to create an instance of the class of that method. Same goes for variables. Example:

```
class Foo
{
    public static void Bar() { ... }
    public void Bar2() { ... }
}

Foo.Bar(); //ok
Foo.Bar2(); //error
```

But remember, a static method cannot access a non-static variable/method in that class.

Answer (score 0):

Its not about the method that is going to be changed .Its about the data that the method is operating on. If its a static method the data it is operating on is not dependent on instance of a type.so we dont need an instance to call it.

Think in terms of data the method operates upon.Is the data dependent on an instance or not.if not mark method as static.